# Angular, PHP vs server

Tags: php, angularjs, сервер, hosting

Здравствуйте добрые люди, у меня проект собранный полностью на Angular JS и PHP, какой сервер использовать чтобы добиться максимальной скорости?

Заранее спасибо! :)

Answer (score 1):

Советую присмотреться к связке Nginx + PHP-FPM.

Почему Nginx, а не Apache? Потому, что Nginx может обслужить большее количество запросов в единицу времени с меньшим расходом памяти. Также в Nginx все настраивается в файле конфигурации или в файле с виртуальным хостом.
Доступ к директории по паролю, разрешенные ip и т.д.

Операционная система - Linux only.

**P.S.** Скорость работы вашего ПО зависит ещё от оптимизированного кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, у меня есть такой вопрос как можно максимально оптимизировать код.Например использование Ng-Repeat в Ng-Repeat и т.д. как то будут влиять на скорость, если да то как можно оптимизировать всё это.)

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/269827/ и http://www.phptherightway.com/